# Longest expiration period for the signed url expiration date (GAE)

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine (java-based) to create a signed url for my files in google cloud storage. According to [google cloud description](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls), we need to define the expiration period. For example, can I create a long-term expiration period like 50 years? Google has not been very specific about this. It has mentioned 7 days, but my signed url has been working beyond 7 days.

On example like:

```
URL signedURL = storage.signUrl(blobinfo, 18000, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Signed URL limit of 7 days of expiration applies to [V4 signing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers). As you are not specifying the signing version in your code, V2 will be used as default.

In the source code of the library in github [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/d32239103e60547f3a6d4ff2445c71132ee46b47/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-storage/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.java#L955) there's a comment stating that the V4 has a 7 day limit but it doesn't say anything about the V2. The [V2 signing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls-v2) doesn't have any specific expiration limit, so the only limitation is the maximum value for int.

If you want to use V4 signing you have to include `withV4Signature()`, for example:

`URL url = storage.signUrl(blobinfo, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES, Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature());`

Comment: I could not find anything in that source code mentioning the signed url doesn't have expiration limit, but I would accept your answer as I use v2 approach.

Comment: Hi, you're right! In the comments says that V4 signing has a limit of 7 days but it doesn't mention explicitly that V2 doesn't have limit. I have implied that since it doesn't mention anything. I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: Google should confirm this that there is no expiration limit. For now, I will not accept this answer until I receive a definite answer.

Comment: Hi, there is no specific expiration limit for V2 signed URLs, it’s just the maximum value for int